# Lexmark Pro805 all-in-one printer fails on Xubuntu 12.04 & 13.10

Tags: 12.04, drivers, xubuntu, printing, lexmark

Downloaded and installed Lexmark's Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit driver from 
http://support.lexmark.com/index?segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_US&locale=en&productCode=LEXMARK_PRESTIGE_PRO805&page=product&frompage=null#2 for their Pro805 all-in-one printer which sits on 192.168.0.6 but printing fails on Xubuntu 12.04 & 13.10  - here's the log from /var/log/cups/error_log available for download at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-lYVa3f8ygJdG1qRkhsZ1B0Y00